# How to get latitude and longitude of place based on specific country?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopy, nominatim

I am working on project to get latitude and longitude of specific place but the result is incorrect because the place i want in 'x country' is the same name in 'y country'.
I want to add country attribute to search result.

I am using this code:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

with open('C:/Users/UI UX/Desktop/test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# print(lines)

for line in lines:
    print(line.replace('\n', ''))
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my_user_agent")
    loc = geolocator.geocode(line)
    print("latitude is :", loc.latitude, "\nlongtitude is:", loc.longitude)
    # print(loc.raw)
    print('Location Address: ' + loc.address)
    print('---------------------------------------------------')
```

Any kind of help please?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Google Maps

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
loc = geolocator.geocode(line, exactly_one=False)
```

It returns a list of locations matching your query. You can find your specific country in the returned list.

[Documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.geocoders.AlgoliaPlaces.geocode)

Answer (score 1):

In your geocode request you can specify a list of countries with this syntax: `geocode(countries = your_list)`. The countries can be specified by two letter country codes (ISO 3166-1).

See geopy documentation [here](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.geocoders.AlgoliaPlaces.geocode) and list of country codes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes).

For example

```
mycountries = [US,]
loc = geolocator.geocode(line, countries = mycountries)
```